# Mapping abstract or undefined references to entities when more specific input is desired

Tags: nlp, chatbot, amazon-lex

We have an application in which we will be collecting addresses from users. In the current implementation, we are using a live agent to do this. Some users, when prompted for a final billing address, will say things like "Just use my billing address" or "same as my current address". THe new implementation will be a chatbot to try and fulfill some of these requests before they get to an agent.

We do have this information available via API lookup, I am asking more from a design perspective how to let our handler app (usually an AWS lambda) know that we need to do the lookup before we prompt to confirm fulfillment.

A few things I thought of:

1. Train the NLP to detect strings "current address" and "billing address" as Address entities
2. Create a new intent for utterances like these and handle them separately
3. Create a new entity type in the current intent (eg, not postalAddress) for utterances like these and handle them as part of the same fulfillment
4. Simply re-prompting the user, or asking them to state what their address is

I am just looking for the most pragmatic approach here, as this problem is different from most others we've solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, and after investigation found that option 3 is the easiest way to handle this.

You can add a `validation hook` that fires when the new `slot` is populated. This hook can populate the value of the `postalAddress` `slot` with the associated address. This way you can keep the `postalAddress` slot as a required slot, without having the user manually state the address.

You can also have this `validation hook` fire on the population of `postalAddress` and add some manual testing for *billing* and *current*, but this felt to me like a manual work around for something that should be automated by Lex.

Comment: If you found an alternative solution, I'd be interested to hear it.